# How to get the current iteration of each() loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        $('#selectDropDowns select').each(function() {

            // do usual stuff

            // do extra stuff only if this is the 4th iteration

        });
```

In order to do the extra stuff on the 4th iteration, how can I detect it?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        $('#selectDropDowns select').each(function(i) {

            // do usual stuff
            if (i==3)
            {
              // do extra stuff only if this is the 4th iteration
            }

        });
```

Comment: That is the 5th iteration. zero index based.

Answer (score 2):

The function you pass to [`each(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) can take two arguments - the index and the element. This is the first thing you see when you open the documentation:

```
 .each( function(index, Element) )
```

So:

```
 $('#selectDropDowns select').each(function(i) {
      if (i == 3) ...
 });
```

Comment: That is the 5th iteration. zero index based.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('#selectDropDowns select').each(function(index, element) {
    // index represents the current index of the iteration
    // and element the current item of the array        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectDropDowns select').each(function(index) {

    // do usual stuff
  if(index ==3){
    // do extra stuff only if this is the 4th iteration
  }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SgMuJ/1/

Comment: @Felix King didn't know you could pass in the index, just created a fiddle works nicely.  Thats why I like this site i learn something new everyday

Comment: That is the 5th iteration. zero index based.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $(this)...

```
    $('#selectDropDowns select').each(function(i, val) {
        //Zero-index based thus to grab 4th iterator -> index = 3
        if (i == 3) {
             alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }

    }
```

Note that you can also get the index and the value of the element in the .each function declaration.

Comment: That is the 5th iteration. zero index based.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to loop through when you can use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
$('#selectDropDowns select').eq( 3 );
```